# Dragging a sprite in sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm doing an assignment at the moment and for it, I need to drag chess pieces on a board, the problem is that I have no idea how to make this work for more than one piece. I can compute the mouse position and I've been able to move just one piece but the code only works for that single piece. My question is how do I click on a piece, have it become the active piece until I release the mouse button. This won't work if I only check if it intersects with one piece because it isn't dynamic then. My code is a mess from me trying different things but here are some of the relevant parts.

Here is the setup for the sprites:

```cpp
// load the texture and setup the sprite for the logo
void Game::setupSprite()
{
    sf::IntRect pieceRect(m_wking.getPosition().x, m_wking.getPosition().y, 128, 128);

    if (!m_boardTexture.loadFromFile("ASSETS\\IMAGES\\board.png"))
    {
        // simple error message if previous call fails
        std::cout << "problem loading board" << std::endl;
    }
    m_boardSprite.setTexture(m_boardTexture);
    m_boardSprite.setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);


    //pieces
    if (!m_wkingTex.loadFromFile("ASSETS\\IMAGES\\PIECES\\wking.png"))
    {
        // simple error message if previous call fails
        std::cout << "problem loading piece" << std::endl;
    }
    m_wking.setTexture(m_wkingTex);
    m_wking.setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);
    sf::IntRect wkingRect(pieceRect);
}
```

If the mouse button is down

```cpp
void Game::processMouseButtonDown(sf::Event t_event)
{
    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left)) {
        std::cout << "Mouse button pressed\n";
        sf::Vector2f mouse = m_window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window));
        if (isSpriteClicked() && !m_holdingPiece) {

            m_holdingPiece = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Mouse button is up:

```cpp
void Game::processMouseButtonUp(sf::Event t_event)
{
    m_holdingPiece = false;
    sf::IntRect pieceRect(m_wking.getPosition().x, m_wking.getPosition().y, 128, 128);
    m_wking.setTextureRect(pieceRect);
}
```

If the sprite is clicked

```cpp
bool Game::isSpriteClicked()
{
    sf::Vector2f mouse = m_window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window));
    sf::FloatRect bounds(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    if (bounds.intersects(wkingRect.I dont know what Im doing)) {

        std::cout << "King has Been clicked!\n";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally to move the sprite:

```cpp
void Game::move()
{
    if (m_holdingPiece) {
        sf::Vector2f mouse = m_window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window));
        m_wking.setPosition(mouse);
    }
}
```

Sorry if that seems like a lot of code, but I feel like it was all relevant to the problem.

Comment: Post a Minimal Reproducible Example. Your example may be minimal, but it is not reproducible. I cannot copy and paste your code in my editor to run it.

Comment: Probably the answer to your problem is to use OOP to  create an object for each piece with a move function.

Comment: @GaryNLOL Copy and pasting this code won't do anything because it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to essentially tag certain sprites as draggable. So that the code detects that what I'm clicking on is in fact a sprite and it is also a draggable sprite, then it drags that sprite until I release the mouse button, my code doesn't do that so reproducing it won't help

Comment: It won't help by solving the problem itself, but will give us a base to reproduce the problem and help you solve to solve it. As your post is now we would have to create all that base from scratch and will be much harder to help you.

Comment: @GaryNLOL I can't give anything minimal because of what I was given to work with spans over multiple files but I can give a pastebin of the project.
Main.cpp: https://pastebin.com/6CxkmycP
Game.cpp: https://pastebin.com/UEvcUads
Game.h: https://pastebin.com/9ELwSmG6

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You have hardcoded all your variables so even if you create a list and iterate over it to run `Game::move()` it will move all the pieces instead of only one because the variable `m_holdingPiece` is the same for all pieces.

**Solution:**

You should use a more OOP aproach creating a class for the chess pieces while the `Game` class should probably just control when the game starts, when it ends and check whether moves are legal or not. Explaning all that would be too broad Stack Overflow and it's part of the work you must do, so I will just let an example of how a basic `chessPiece` class would be to make pieces dragabble.

**Example:**

Here is an example of how you can make a group of pieces draggable.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

class chessPiece: public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    bool moving;
public:
    chessPiece(sf::RenderWindow& windowRef, const std::string& fileName): window(windowRef)
    {
        if(!texture.loadFromFile(fileName))
            exit(0);
        this->sprite.setTexture(this->texture);
        this->moving = false;
        this->sprite.setScale(128/this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().width,128/this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height);
    }
    chessPiece(chessPiece&& rval): window(rval.window)
    {
        this->texture = std::move(rval.texture);
        this->sprite.setTexture(this->texture);
        this->sprite.setScale(rval.sprite.getScale());
        this->moving = std::move(rval.moving);
    }
    chessPiece(const chessPiece& lval): window(lval.window)
    {
        this->texture = lval.texture;
        this->sprite.setTexture(this->texture);
        this->sprite.setScale(lval.sprite.getScale());
        this->moving = lval.moving;
    }
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= this->getTransform();
        target.draw(this->sprite,states);
    }
    void move(bool& movingAPiece)
    {
        sf::Vector2f mousePosition = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
        if(this->moving)
        {
            this->setPosition(mousePosition.x - this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().width/2,mousePosition.y - this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
            if(!sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))
            {
                this->moving = false;
                movingAPiece = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left) && mousePosition.x > this->getPosition().x &&
               mousePosition.y > this->getPosition().y && mousePosition.x < this->getPosition().x + this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().width &&
               mousePosition.y < this->getPosition().y + this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height && !movingAPiece)
            {
                this->moving = true;
                movingAPiece = true;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000,500),"Window");
    std::vector<chessPiece> pieces = {chessPiece(window,"white-king.png"),chessPiece(window,"white-pawn.png")};
    pieces[0].setPosition(400,400);
    bool movingAPiece = false;
    while(true)
    {
        sf::Event event;
        if(window.pollEvent(event))
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pieces.size(); i++)
            pieces[i].move(movingAPiece);
        window.clear();
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pieces.size(); i++)
            window.draw(pieces[i]);
        window.display();
    }
}
```